# How to add a method in sequelize model using typescript and bcrypt?

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, bcrypt

I'm creating a project in typescript and I'm having troubles with bcrypt and sequelize.

To encrypt passwords I typed this code:

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import { sequelize } from "../dbpostgredatabase";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

export const User = sequelize.define(
  "User",
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },

    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      set(value: string) {
        const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(value, 8);
        this.setDataValue("password", hash);
      },
    },

    lastname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    date: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    admin: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
  },

  {
    timestamps: false,
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false,
  }
);

export default User;
```

I need that hash and I don't now how to get it I just need a method to compare the passwords

Answer (score 0):

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import { sequelize } from "../dbpostgredatabase";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

export const User = sequelize.define(
  "User",
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },

    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      set(value: string) {
        const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(value, 8);
        this.setDataValue("password", hash);
      },
    },

    lastname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    date: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    admin: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
  },

  {
    timestamps: false,
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false,
  }
);

// add static method here
User.hashPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
}

User.isValidPassword = function(password, hash) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(hash, password);
}

export default User;
```

Comment: Hi, It's my first time using typescript so I suppose that I have to add something  

 ![code](https://i.imgur.com/icrLDGs.png)